# What's the real yield on this bond?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

I've never bought bonds before and I'm looking into US Treasuries. The 3mo treasury below is described as having a ~4.9% yield. How is this number derived?

To me, it looks like if I buy this note with a face value of $100, I have to pay $98.41716667. So, when it matures, I've earned $1.58283333, which is ~1.583%, correct?

[image]

Comment: Not a complete answer but the 1.6% is over the course of 3 months. The 4.9% is annualized.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a Fidelity calculator](https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/priceyieldcalc/). It will give you a ballpark figure. It's useful when there is a coupon in addition to the premium or discount.

Comment: [see here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/154690/109107) for an example computation

Answer (score 4):

The 1.6% is what you get over the course of 3 months. The 4.9% is annualized.

Here are the actual formulas, if you want to replicate the calculations yourself: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/preanre/2004/ofcalc6decbill.pdf

[image: Daily Treasury Bill Rates]

Please keep in mind that you're looking a T-bills, which are zero-coupon and have their own pricing conventions (ACT/360 instead of ACT/ACT):

> The Bank Discount rate is the rate at which a bill is quoted in the secondary market and is based on the par value, amount of the discount and a 360-day year. The Coupon Equivalent, also called the Bond Equivalent, or the Investment Yield, is the bill's yield based on the purchase price, discount, and a 365- or 366-day year. The Coupon Equivalent can be used to compare the yield on a discount bill to the yield on a nominal coupon security that pays semiannual interest with the same maturity date.

source: https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_bill_rates&field_tdr_date_value_month=202303

Comment: Just realized I highlighted the 3/14 instead of the 3/13 but close enough...